# Brushless dc motor

Tags: motor, dc, brushless-dc-motor

I am working on Brush less dc motor driving circuit,in this i use six MOSFET for switching purpose and 3 hall effect sensor for detecting the position of rotor.and this i choose **AN 2212 brush less motor**.but the main question is that how to connect
hall effect sensor outside the motor and what position it can fixed ?

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the current design?

Answer (score 0):

You can either install external magnets on the shaft or rotor, or sense the magnets inside the rotor. If you use external magnets then arrange them at 120º angles around the shaft or rotor, and mount the sensors on a ring which can be turned to get the correct alignment.

To sense the internal rotor magnets place the hall sensors between 3 adjacent windings, like this:-

[image]

Your motor is probably wound 'LRK' style where each winding goes around *two* adjacent stator arms, so you may need to experiment to determine which slots to put the sensors in.

To check the positioning, first turn the motor by hand and make sure the hall sensors are producing the correct sequence (if not you may need to switch the wires or rotate one or more sensors).

Then spin the motor fast enough to see the back-emf waveform, and compare the back-emf and sensor waveforms on a dual trace oscilloscope. If you don't have a scope then put enough current through one winding to get the rotor to align, then adjust the position of the sensor that switches that phase so it is just changing over.

Once you have the right sequence and timing close enough to run the motor, you can fine tune the sensor positions for smooth running with minimum idle current.

Note that if you get the sequence wrong or the timing badly off then the motor may run very rough or not spin at all, and draw very high current. Always use a current-limited power supply when testing!